# Exception when reading text from the file using FileIO.ReadTextAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am getting the following exception when attempting to read a locl text file using

```
var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

> The handle with which this oplock was associated has been closed.  The
>   oplock is now broken. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070323)

This happens in one of the regression unit tests, it also happens from time to time in the app. App is XAML + C#

Any ideas what might be causing it?!

Comment: You're reading from a network share, aren't you?

Comment: No, I am reading from a local file

Comment: Is there anything unusual about the file you are reading? Is it particularly large?

Comment: @VictorOliveira Nope, I have abandoned that project, but we never got to solve that issue.

Comment: I was having the same problem, that ocurred by concurrence threading. I was trying to acess the same file in two places at the same time and didn't realize it.

Comment: @VictorOliveira This is in fact what could have happened, but I won't be able to verify that. But you can still post it as an answer, might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem, that ocurred by concurrence threading. I was trying to acess the same file in two places at the same time and didn't realize it.

Try to verify your code looking for some another acess to the same file and verify if you are closing after read it, and don't forget to call "await" or use a lock in every file reading. I think it may solve your issue.

Comment: I can't verify that solution is working, but from the description it seems that it's exactly what I was doing in the project.

Comment: I had the same error.  Per the hint of this answer, I found it was caused by a BitmapDecoder accessing a file that is not available anymore.